# search in MySQL database based on alphabet's position?

Tags: mysql

I want to search in my database "emp" for names which have the alphabet "A" as third alphabet from left in their names.

This is what I tried:

```
select empname from emp
where left(empname,3)="a"
order by empname;
```

It returns an empty set.
Can you check my syntax, whether it is correct or not!

(Upvote promised ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`left(empname,3)` will return the three leftmost characters in the string.

You need `substring(empname,3,1)`, which will start at the third character and return a string of length 1.

The reference is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Your query becomes:

```
select empname from emp
  where substring(empname,3,1)="a"
  order by empname;
```

Answer (score 0):

**The INSTR() function returns the position of the first occurrence of a string in another string. This function performs a case-insensitive search.**

`Select INSTR(first_name, 'm') from Tablename where first_name = 'monika';`

Reference:- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_instr.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31731512)